# How to keep an Android service running forever

Tags: android, android-studio

My Android app has a long running service. You can close the app, and the service will continue to run. Even if the phone is sleeping, the service will continue to run. But after about 2 hours of the phone sitting still, no interaction, the service stops running. I would need to unlock my phone, launch the app again, then the service would come back alive. Is there a way to have this background service to run forever, even when the phone is sleeping?

Comment: Please read: [Doze mode](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby) and be aware of https://dontkillmyapp.com/

Answer (score 0):

Your phone's power-saving mode is probably to blame for the problem you're having. Your phone might go into a power-saving mode after a certain period of inactivity that limits background processes in order to preserve battery life.

Use the Foreground Service API to shield your app's background service from the effects of power saving mode. With the help of this API, you may build a foreground service that notifies the user that your app is active in the background. The Android operating system gives foreground services a higher priority, and power-saving modes are less likely to have an impact on them.